# JavaFX MenuItem.setAccelerator( ) not working

Tags: javafx-2, accelerator

I want my JavaFX program to be able to dynamically change the accelerator for menu items.  However, I can't seem to get it to work in JavaFX 2.2.  In the code below, the first menu item has an accelerator "Ctrl+M" and it works fine. "Ctrl+M" is printed every time the menu item is selected using a mouse or with the keyboard accelerator Ctrl+M.  The second menu item attempts to change the first men item's accelerator to "Ctrl+L".  After choosing the second menu item, I can click on the first menu item again and it shows that its new accelerator is "Ctrl+L", but I cannot use the keyboard accelerator Ctrl+L to activate the first menu item.  Instead, I still need to use Ctrl+M to activate the first menu item.  Any suggestions on what is going wrong here?

```
/*
 * from code at <http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/02/javafx-20-set-accelerator.html>
 */
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AcceleratorExample extends Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Accelerator example");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300, Color.WHITE);
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

        Menu FileMenu = new Menu("File");

        final MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("Select me");
        item1.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+M"));
        item1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(item1.getAccelerator());
            }
        });

        final MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("New accel");
        item2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                item1.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+L"));
            }
        });

        FileMenu.getItems().add(item1);
        FileMenu.getItems().add(item2);
        menuBar.getMenus().add(FileMenu);

        menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Dynamically changing the accelerator has iffy behaviour at present, but this is a bug which has been fixed for 8u20:

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35182